# Intellij - Generated source code should not be edited (even though it's not generated)

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I have a file that just exports a few modules:

```
export * from './A'
export * from './B'
export * from './C'
```

But now when I try adding more exports, I get a warning at the top of the file saying:

`Generated source code should not be edited.  The changes will be lost when sources are regenerated.`

I'm not really sure what that means since I manually type the export lines as I add more modules.  The warning actually disappears if I add some normal js code like a random function (compared to just having exports).

Should I be concerned with the warning? How do I make it go away?

I'm using WebStorm 2016.2 EAP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IDE treats this file as minified; Please follow [WEB-21928](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21928) for updates

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about your project setup but IntelliJ distinguishes from managed and generated sources. So maybe the source folder is marked as generated sources root? To change that, simply use the context menu on the directory in the project structure:

[image]

Comment: When I right-click the directory and go to `Mark Directory As`, the only options I have are, `Resource Root`, `Excluded`, and `Test Sources Root`.  Maybe it's just a bug?

Comment: Seems to be webstorm related, I only use normal community or ultimate version

Answer (score 1):

You won't see "Unmark Sources Root" unless "Resources Root" had been selected.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue with:

> ```
> export const a="a";
> export const b="b";
> export const c="c";
> ```

but when I change syntax instead of it with:

> ```
> const a="a";
> const b="b";
> const c="c";
> export {a, b, c};
> ```

webStore stop to showing this warning. Maybe multiple export creating problems.